# GROUP BY in query

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a little struggle with this query. The GROUP BY function is not working in this query. Without the webshop group by it works, but multiple webshops show. Maybe anyone got an idea? Thanks!

```
SELECT 
    default_deals.id, 
    default_deals.title,
    default_webshops.name,
    COUNT(default_deals_categories.categories_id) as category_count,
    default_webshops.popular,
    default_webshops.popular_order
FROM 
    default_deals
    JOIN default_deals_categories ON default_deals.id = default_deals_categories.row_id
    JOIN default_webshops ON default_deals.webshop = default_webshops.id
WHERE 
    categories_id IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY 
    default_deals.id, 
    default_deals.title,
    default_webshops.name,
    default_webshops.popular,
    default_webshops.popular_order
ORDER BY 
    category_count DESC, 
    default_webshops.popular DESC, 
    default_webshops.popular_order DESC
```

Comment: Could you share some data to replicate the issue. Looking at the query it looks good

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    default_deals.id, 
    title,
    name,
    COUNT(categories_id) as category_count,
    popular,
    popular_order
FROM 
    default_deals
    JOIN default_deals_categories ON default_deals.id = default_deals_categories.row_id
    JOIN default_webshops ON default_deals.webshop = default_webshops.id
WHERE 
    categories_id IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY 
    default_deals.id, 
    title,
    name,
    popular,
    popular_order
ORDER BY 
    category_count DESC, 
    popular DESC, 
    popular_order DESC
```

Okay, I guess your results have a deal listed multiple times with each webshop it has been linked to and then the same category count but possibly different values for popular and popular_order?  What you need to do is to decide how you want to aggregate these fields.  For example, you could do this:

```
SELECT 
    dd.id, 
    dd.title,
    MAX(dw.name) AS webshop_name,
    COUNT(dc.categories_id) AS category_count,
    MAX(dw.popular) AS popular,
    SUM(dw.popular_order) AS popular_order
FROM 
    default_deals dd
    JOIN default_deals_categories dc ON dd.id = dc.row_id
    JOIN default_webshops dw ON dd.webshop = dw.id
WHERE 
    dc.categories_id IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY
    dd.id, 
    dd.title
ORDER BY 
    COUNT(dc.categories_id) DESC, 
    MAX(dw.popular) DESC, 
    SUM(dw.popular_order) DESC;
```

But I am going to bet that is NOT what you actually want to see.  Where you have multiple webshops what do you want to see?  My example just takes the highest value alphabetically but you could make this into a list, e.g. "Webshop1, Webshop2", etc.

You also need to decide how to aggregate the other fields in the webshop table.  My query takes the maximum for popular and the sum of popular_order but this is just an example.

Finally, this will double up, triple up, etc. the category count depending on how many webshops a deal is linked to... and I am going to bet that this is also not what you want?

Comment: unfortunately it gives the same result :(

Comment: Which field comes from which table, e.g. you specify this for the first column (default_deals.id) but not for any of the others?  Also, what do you actually see and what do you want to see?  Your original query was trying to GROUP BY a column that wasn't in the results so I took it out and "fixed" the query to GROUP BY the non-aggregated columns.  Maybe try adding the default_deals.webshop column back to the GROUP BY clause?

Comment: It still returns multiple webshops, it should return one deal per webshop

Comment: I would need a sample of data, what currently shows and what you want to show to be able to help you further I'm afraid then...